# difference between oracle 11.2.0.1 to 11.2.0.2

Tags: oracle-11g

In my environment Oracle 11g version 11.2.0.1 was installed and it was working ok. Now I am considering upgrading to version 11.2.0.2.

What is the main difference between 11.2.0.1 and 11.2.0.2.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably start with the [New Features Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22487/toc.htm) and in particular the [section on 11.2.0.2](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22487/chapter1_2.htm#NEWFTCH1-b).

Note that:

1. 11.2.0.2 is a minor release so for most purposes it will not be much different to 11.2.0.1
2. depending on your platform, 11.2.0.2 may not be the latest available (eg 11.2.0.3 on Linux)